# The Bohr's atomic model: what does a long dash (——) in the numerator mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, notation, textbook-erratum

While studying Bohr's atomic model from a book on semiconductor, namely SOLID STATE ELECTRONIC DEVICES ($6^{th}$ edition) by Streetman and Banerjee, I saw *a long dash character* probably a long horizontal bar in the numerator at two places, which I've highlighted in the attached image with yellow boxes: what does the authors mean by that long dash(——) in the numerator?[image]

Comment: So, you find a symbol you don't understand in one book and you don't have the curiosity to check any other standard book on the subject first?

Comment: I did prove, looked other resources, and I saw it was weird for at least 3 hours but it was my *inner mind* which had some suspicions. For the sake of others interest I can, if you say, delete this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some kind of goofy typo to me. Take a look, for instance, at http://www.tutorvista.com/content/physics/physics-iv/atoms-and-nuclei/bohrs-hydrogen-atom.php#derivation-of-radius for a similar derivation without the "$\_\_2$" thing. The usual Bohr orbit radius result is $r_n=\frac{4\pi\epsilon_0n^2\hbar^2}{me^2}$, so I guess his $q\sim e$ (pretty obvious), and his $K=4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2$. And there just ain't no "$\_\_2$" kind of thing anywhere.

**Edit...** as per comments below, I found you can download this book from https://archive.org/details/fe_Solid-State-Electronic-Devices-6th-Edition where they give Eq(2-6) as $$-\frac{q^2}{Kr^2}=-\frac{mv^2}{r}$$ and Eq(2-7) as $${p}_\theta=mvr=n\hbar$$ And the text defines $K=4\pi\epsilon_0$ as usual, i.e., without the $\hbar^2$ I threw in above to get the right answer.

Now, just do the algebra **as given by the textbook itself** and you get the answer without the "goofy $2\_\_2$". You just get $2$. Moreover, you can see they've also lost a factor of $\hbar^2$, just doing the algebra from their own equations, which is why I threw it into $K$.

What's really weird to me is that this is the 6th edition. How the heck did such blatant typos make it past the editors into print???

Comment: @DeepChandra Just google "Bohr radius derivation", or similar, for other derivations. And **even better** prove it to yourself -- plug the Eq(2-8) result you're showing back into Eq(2-6), like the text says, and see what happens (you probably should have shown us Eq(2-6) and Eq(2-7) also). It's just some pretty simple algebra, not rocket science:)

Comment: @DeepChandra see **edit** in answer above for some additional info...

Comment: As you said, I had it proved myself, but for convincing myself made a question here to make sure that what if that typo thing may have been there to mean something. You are absolutely right. I think there's, indeed, a need of a good publisher which maintains such a strong track of these inevitable errors from its readers and corrects it in each subsequent reprints. Thanks for your help. I really feel annoyed with such typos.

Comment: I'm reading the same book SOLID STATE ELECTRONIC DEVICES with the same edition, 6th. I'm editing the question to reflect the book-name.